# onChange to Run ONLY if A3 has data - Google Apps Script / Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to get this script to only run if is sees data in A3. the data is coming to this sheet from another sheet. I tried the onChange but it wouldnt trigger when the new data arrived in "Top Up Needed". add the onchange to the project triggers but still doesnt run script.

```
function TopUpNeeded() {

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('TOP UP NEEDED'), true);
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('TOP UP NEEDED');
  sheet.getRange('J3').activate().setFormula('=QUERY({\'SKU & Qty\'!$A$3:$C},"SELECT * WHERE Col1 MATCHES \'" & JOIN("|",FILTER(I2:I, NOT(ISBLANK(I2:I)))) & "\' ")');

}
```

also tried this code above my code,but no good.

```
  function onChange() {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    ScriptApp.newTrigger("TopUpNeeded")
     .forSpreadsheet(sheet)
     .onChange()
     .create();
  }
```

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### `onChange` does not run if changes were not made by a human, see [restrictions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#restrictions)

The exception is if the data is being updated with the cell formula [IMPORTRANGE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340?hl=en)

You can paste into cell "A3" of sheet "Top Up Needed" the formula

`IMPORTRANGE(spreadsheet_url, range_string)`

specifying the spreadsheet and range that is expected to populate the cell content.

In this case your first function will fire on `onChange` trigger each time the content of `A3` updates.