# Google sheets to Calendar - Update previous event script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, calendar

I have a budget set in Sheets and a script to update my calendar with the due dates. My script is:

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Sync to Calendar')
      .addItem('Unpaid Items', 'unpaidItems')
      .addItem('Delete All', 'deleteEvent')
      .addToUi();
};

function unpaidItems() {
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

//First Calendar beceause of different colour
var calendarId = spreadsheet.getRange("K72").getValue();
var eventCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);

//Second Calendar beceause of different colour
var calendarIdPaid = spreadsheet.getRange("K71").getValue();
var eventCalPaid = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarIdPaid);


var signups = spreadsheet.getRange("B15:I16").getValues();

  for (x=0; x<signups.length; x++) {
    var shift = signups[x];
    var statt = shift[7];    

    if (statt == "Required Soon" ) {
       var Debtor = shift[0];
       var startTime = shift[6];
       var endTime = shift[6];
       eventCal.createAllDayEvent(Debtor, startTime, endTime+1);
      //Ideally to use a single calendar and change the color of this entry
    }
    else if (statt == "Late Payment" ) {
       var Debtor = shift[0];
       var startTime = shift[6];
       var endTime = shift[6];
       eventCal.createAllDayEvent(Debtor, startTime, endTime+1);
      //Ideally to use a single calendar and change the color of this entry
    }
    else if (statt == "Paid" ) {
       var Debtor = shift[0];
       var startTime = shift[6];
       var endTime = shift[6];
       eventCalPaid.createAllDayEvent(Debtor, startTime, endTime+1);
      //Ideally to use a single calendar and change the color of this entry
      //This entry would have existed under Required soon or Late Payment so that has to be deleted now and replaced with this in a green colour showing its been paid
    }
  }
}
```

** All works but in the "For" section there's a few hashed out items. How can I:

1. Use a single calendar but change the color of the entry event based on if its Required soon, Late Payment or Paid?
2. More importantly, Once an item has been paid this is flagged in the sheet but it still has to be removed from my calendar or updated with a green colour to indicate its now been paid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### You can set event colors with the method [setColor(color)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event#setcolorcolor)

Thereby, you can chose between event colors, as specified [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/event-color.html).

Just implement in each of your `if` statements an event color as desired, e.g.

```
    ...
    else if (statt == "Paid" ) {
       var Debtor = shift[0];
       var startTime = shift[6];
       var endTime = shift[6];
       var event = eventCalPaid.createAllDayEvent(Debtor, startTime, endTime+1);
       event.setColor(CalendarApp.EventColor.GREEN);      
    }
    ...
```

**UPDATE**

if you want to verify first either an event exists and modify if does - you can do it as following:

```
    ...
    else if (statt == "Paid" ) {
       var Debtor = shift[0];
       var startTime = shift[6];
       var endTime = shift[6];
       var events = eventCal.getEvents(startTime, endTime, {search : Debtor});
       var event = events[0];
       if(!event){
        var event = eventCal.createAllDayEvent(Debtor, startTime, endTime);
       }
       event.setColor(CalendarApp.EventColor.GREEN);      
    }
    ...
```

> Be careful with `endTime+1`, your event might not be found if the
>   times don't correspond.

Comment: Cool tx that works as requested. Would you perhaps know the question 2 part as well? Basically updating the item from its previous status or deleting the previous status and adding it again.

Comment: Can you explain this a bit more detailed? You mean instead of creating a new event, updating an already existing one? What is your criteria for deciding that an event exists already? The title?

Comment: This is for a bugdet. I have columns for Start and end date (same column), title and a staus. The status is empty until start date is 7 days from today. So in 7 days the account is due. Status is now Required Soon. If you pass the due date then its Late payment. Then when its paid its marked as Paid. At the end of the first else if (late payment) it has to delete the entry for Required soon and replace with late payment. At the second if late payment has to be del. And paid should show. Data never changes so either can be used to del the previous entry.

Comment: This is the template - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VtS4ufQy6l5qHUDVILyld95V6izXBrlvgbQ1IejUOIs/edit?usp=sharing

I've updated the code a bit to remove the endate+1 and also to a single calendar. That works well. I've added your latest code but it doesn't update the previous record. You can make a copy of the file and just save your own calendar key in K28. Then you can run the script. Car Instalment will be in red in your calendar. Then change I15 to "Paid" and run it. You'll see another entry that's now in green. But the red entry should now have been deleted.

Comment: What do you mean by "update the previous record"? Do you mean to update it in the calendar or in the spreadsheet?

Comment: Sorry should have made it more cleared. Basically update in both. So say 1 March I have to pay "Car Installment". 7 Days before 1 March the field in excel will auto generate "Required Soon". This will then show in the calendar (Orange). If the excel cell isn't updated to "Paid" manually then it goes to "Late payment" (red) and this has to show on the calendar. So the orange entry should be updated in the calendar. IF you update the excel sheet to state "Paid" then the "Required soon" or "Late Payment" has to be removed from the calendar and it should show in green as its been paid.

Comment: So you update the excel cell and that should push through to update the calendar based on the criteria you've entered. At the moment it pushes through but each cell change goes into a new event. So if its required soon initially but it moves over to late payment then both will still show on the calendar. If you manually make it as Paid it will show 3 events for the 1 day where it should delete the Required soon and Late Payment entry.

Comment: So the title of your calendar event is e.g. `Car Installment` and there is only one event with this title? And the start and end date of an event remain fixed? In this case `var events = eventCal.getEvents(startTime, endTime, {search : Debtor});` should find the event if it is in your calendar already.

Comment: When it comes to changes in the spreadsheet,  for automatic status updates, you cannot directly run the script on update - you need to either use [script properties](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service#getScriptProperties()) to compare the status to the one that was present last time you open the sheet, or you need to use an `onchange` trigger in combination with `importrange` as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60207874/onchange-to-run-only-if-a3-has-data-google-apps-script-google-sheets/60210100#60210100).

Comment: Auto update I"m talking about is just on a calc field using "today" as a date. I still have to open it but it will check todays date vs when it has to be paid and if its overdue it will auto update the "status" cell from Required soon to Late Payment. 

The title and date will never change on the spreadsheet but using the code above doesn't work. It simply adds another entry into the calendar. Note that when an event is now added its added with Debtor, StarTime and that's it. No more endTime. If I left it with the same date it gave me errors and you suggested +1 isn't a good idea.

Comment: I see now - this is the problem! To find already existing events, you NEED to specify an end time, otherwise the method does not work. You just need to make sure the endtime of your event is inside the specified end time for the search. As for automatic updates - updates made by formulas unfortunately also count as such.