# Fullcalendar styling differentes events

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fullcalendar, google-calendar-api

Is there a way to have multiple colors on events using Google Calendar API on FullCalendar?
I have 3 categories of events and  I want to style them in different ways, but I haven´t found a way to give them a class or ID.

Keep in my that I know you can custom single events like the example on the link below, but my question is how can you this when all of them come from the same source (Google Calendar API)?

https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-colors-demo

Comment: Well the obvious first question is: how do you know what "category" your event belongs to? Is there a property of the event data which shows it? Or something which can be parsed from the title, perhaps? Please tell us. fullCalendar preserves certain properties of google calendar events when it downloads them and turns them into fullCalendar events (assuming you're using the ready-made plugin to load them). If there is, then you can use the [eventDataTransform](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventDataTransform) callback to read that value, and use it to set the colour property of each event.

Comment: In fact the [documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/google-calendar) says "Google Calendar’s API allows you to specify Extended Properties for your events. The extended properties will be available in the extendedProps hash of each Event Object.". So you could potentially do it that way. But it depends, how you are defining a "category" in this context, exactly.

Comment: You can set an event color in function of e.g. the event summary or description, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60266636/11599789)

Comment: @ziganoyschka this question is about changing the colour in [fullCalendar](https://fullCalendar.io), not Google calendar itself